# how to use a hidden input field to store a blog post's set of tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, user-interface, tagging

I have some slightly funky UI for inputting tags for a blog post: as tags are entered into an input field they are wrapped into spans that make them look nice by surrounding them in a stylized box, the end result comes out to be something like this:
http://forr.st/posts/OLs/original

Now, this input field (call it field 1)is not part of the form that gets submitted to the controller (I'm using RoR btw) for two reasons: it contains extraneous html tags, besides the actual tags; also if it was part of the form pressing enter would submit the form instead of triggering the js that wraps the entered tag into a span.

So what I'm doing is when each tag is entered, I copy its value (via js) to a hidden input field that IS part of the tag entry form, and when submitted would contain only the tag values and nothing else. The question is: What should I use as delimiter to separate the tags in the hidden input field. Currently I'm using ';' but if a tag itself contains ; that'd cause problems.

I'm also open to suggestions about the general method of how to keep track of the tags entered into 'field 1'

Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend just adding a hidden input for each tag.

```
<input type="hidden" name="post[tags][]" value="tag_name" />
<input type="hidden" name="post[tags][]" value="tag_name" />
<input type="hidden" name="post[tags][]" value="tag_name" />
```

then in rails

post.rb

```
def tags=(value)
   tag_array = [*value]
   # then just filter these out.
end
```

I use a similar method with the tokenInput jQuery plugin.  But in my case I've placed it inside the form.  I solved the problems that you mentioned by capturing the keypress event and preventing it for that input and I ignore the search input value.

The one thing that I really like about keeping it inside the form is how it is managed afterward.  I place the hidden tag, name, and a remove 'x' in a span (like you mentioned) and then just remove this tag when the 'x' is clicked. I like this because the name and the hidden_tag are removed at the same time.

Just one other tip. If you can, pass the tag_id in the hidden field. This way you don't have to add the tags attribute add all: `<input type="hidden" name="post[tag_ids][]" value="tag_name" />`.

Comment: that was a great response, thanks! and the plugin you mentioned is exactly what I'm looking for. One question though on the plug in: is there a way to allow users to enter tags that are not in the autocomplete, ie user enters tag, doesn't scroll down to select anything from the autocomplete list and just presses enter and the tag is simply added as was entered. Thanks a lot!

Comment: tokenInput works much the way I describe above with hidden_tags in the labels.  You could watch for when the enter key is pressed and then manually add the tag.  I am sure there are a bunch of ways to do this and others might answer differently. I did it a bit different.  In my JSON autocomplete response, I added an 'Add: #{ q }' at the top.  This forces a click–to prevent accidental adds by pressing the enter key. Then from the model, I pulled the ids that were strings and created a new tag.  The rest I just added with tag_ids.  This is a bit vague; let me know if you want an example.